# [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments Error?

Tags: php, implode

I am getting the following error,

```
[08-Mar-2013 22:10:20] PHP Warning: implode() 
[<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: 
Invalid arguments passed in /home5/palekico/public_html/_import/functions.php 
on line 235
```

Here is the Line:

```
<p class="bline"><strong>Cast: </strong> <?= implode("<br>", $p['cast']); ?></p>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What's in $p['cast'] ?

Comment: $p['cast'][] = tidy($c); I guess. I am not sure where to find that.

Comment: Implode only works on strings.  Try `<?php print_r($p['cast']); ?>` instead and see what it prints.

Comment: I do not see anything.

Comment: I replaced "<?= implode("<br>", $p['cast']); ?>" with "<?php print_r($p['cast']); ?>"

Comment: I guess $p['cast'] is null or undefined then.  That would be why implode finds it invalid.

Comment: I see the following:    
         // get the cast
 $cast = get_surrounding('<h2>Cast</h2>', '</table>', $page);
 $cast = explode('<td class="name">', $cast);
 unset($cast[0]);
 
 foreach ($cast as $c)
 {
  $p['cast'][] = tidy($c)